# How do I go about heading down the Independent Road?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I want to do an independent ending of New Vegas but I can't figure out how to do it. Last time I found myself on the NCR ending without even realizing it. How do I start the Independent road?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Since we're talking about endings, spoilers ahoy!)

The "independent New Vegas" ending is all about Yes Man.  You'll first encounter Yes Man on the 13th floor of The Tops casino, and he'll discuss Benny's plan with you after you've dealt with Benny, either by killing him or having him flee.  Discuss Benny's plan with Yes Man, and he'll explain what needs to be done to finish this quest line.

You can switch factions even late into the game, so don't worry too much if you've started down some NCR, Legion, or House questlines before you start dealing with Yes Man.  You'll get a warning from each of the other factions in the form of a new quest when you're nearing the point of no return.

The "No Gods, No Masters" ending is also the "catch-all" ending if you end up doing a lot of really bad things to everyone.  If you want to ensure you can't possibly win the game any other way, try killing all the leaders of all the other factions.  You'll be in for a fight, but you'll have locked in your ending choice...

Comment: I would just like to add that the game warns you when you are about to do something that would prevent one of the 4 major endings if you are still on the fence about deciding which end you want.